# NetSuite Intercompany Drop Ship Freight

Tags: transactions, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

We are continuing to implement our NetSuite application and we have run into an issue. When there is an intercompany drop shipment order, the freight that is on the original sales order does not transfer to the paired sales order. Does anyone have experience in linking the paired purchase order and paired sales order via SuiteScript to automatically pull in the correct shipping item? I am new to SuiteScript and I prefer to learn. If you can be of assistance or know someone that could be of assistance, that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign it via script, we have a similar process and use an intercompany transaction custom record to match which ship mapping goes where.

Comment: Thanks pipechang! I am a novice at SuiteScript - so look for more questions posted to the board :-)

Comment: pipechang and others, I have been successful in getting a table setup for the cross reference shipping methods and applying the new method to the paired sales order, however, I am getting a "You cannot change the GL impact for intercompany inventory transfer lines" message. Any thoughts on how to get past this message?

Comment: Seems like you're attempting to change item lines or the total order value. Is this new shipping method changing any of these?

Comment: pipechang, I found that after the intercompany paired sales order has been created, you cannot change a field that has a potential GL impact. In this case, it could impact freight revenue or expense with the change in ship method. I was able to get around this by calling at the before record submit function as opposed to after record submit.

Comment: Good call. Guess that fixes the issue.